# TypeScript overloading method on base-type string

Tags: javascript, typescript, overloading

TypeScript-Version: 1.6

I'm trying to add another overload-function for `String`s `replace`-function which should have the following signature:

```
replace(searchValue: string, replaceValue: any): string;
```

So it can be used like

```
"someString".replace("replaceMe", $(evt.target).data("row-id"))
```

I need `any` as of `.data` is defined as:

```
data(key: string): any;
```

My `String.d.ts` (declaration)

```
interface String {
    /**
      * Replaces text in a string, using a regular expression or search string.
      * @param searchValue A string that represents the regular expression.
      * @param replaceValue A string containing the text to replace for every successful match of searchValue in this string.
      */
    replace(searchValue: string, replaceValue: any): string;
}
```

My `String.ts` (implementation)

```
String.prototype.replace = (searchValue: string, replaceValue: any):string =>
{
    if (replaceValue instanceof String) {
        var stringReplacement = replaceValue.toString();
        return String.prototype.replace(stringReplacement, replaceValue);
    } else {
        return replaceValue;
    }
}
```

The following error is thrown and I'm not sure why and how it can be fixed:

> Error TS2322 Type '(searchValue: string, replaceValue: any) => string' is not assignable to type '{ (searchValue: string, replaceValue: string): string; (searchValue: string, replacer: (substring...'.
>   Types of parameters 'searchValue' and 'searchValue' are incompatible.
>   Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'RegExp'.
>   Property 'exec' is missing in type 'String'.

**Edit #1**

I ended up with just the declaration for `replace` (and removement of the implementation) to satisfy the compiler:

```
interface String {
    /**
      * Replaces text in a string, using a regular expression or search string.
      * @param searchValue A string that represents the regular expression.
      * @param replaceValue A string containing the text to replace for every successful match of searchValue in this string.
      */
    replace(searchValue: string, replaceValue: any): string;
}
```

Is this still wrong as of internally it still calls the `replace`-function of the library?

**Edit #2**

If using nothing own Visual Studio is yelling

[image: Withour cast]

With cast it shows (ReSharper)

[image: ReSharper says]

With example 4.1 (MartyIX)

[image: With variable declaration]

Comment: So, I don't know anything about typescript, but I don't see what this method does that you can't already do with `String.prototype.replace`?

Comment: It seems like TS functions are invariant on parameter types and `f(string, any)` can't be saved into a value of type `f(string, string)`.

Comment: @Mathletics it get's me an error at compile-time as of in typescript there is no definition for `replace(string, any)`

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: So it's because of `any` <-> `string` can't be distinguished?

Answer (score 2):

Doing `"someString".replace("replaceMe", $(evt.target).data("row-id"));` should work because `any` can be assigned to `string`. I'm not sure why you're getting an error, but I would recommend making sure the function signatures with `string` as the first parameter for `replace` haven't been removed from `lib.d.ts`. You can double check that by going to the definition of replace (put cursor on replace and hit F12) and making sure it has all the function signatures shown below. You can also try disabling resharper temporarily to see if that makes the error go away.

By the way, to fix your error with overriding `String.prototype.replace`, it already has these possible function signatures:

```
replace(searchValue: string, replaceValue: string): string;
replace(searchValue: string, replacer: (substring: string, ...args: any[]) => string): string;
replace(searchValue: RegExp, replaceValue: string): string;
replace(searchValue: RegExp, replacer: (substring: string, ...args: any[]) => string): string;
```

What was written is not compatible when `searchValue` is a `RegExp`, so you need to change the function signature to allow both `string` and `RegExp` by using a union type:

```
String.prototype.replace = function(searchValue: string | RegExp, replaceValue: any) {
    // omitted
}
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to do though because the function will do an infinite loop. Maybe you meant to hold a reference to the original `String.prototype.replace` and call that? Remember that when you assign to `String.prototype.replace` you overwrite the original function.

**Overall though don't do what's being done here**. Look up "don't modify objects you don't own" to see what I mean. It would be better if you create your own separate function to do this because *right now this replace function breaks any code that uses it*. You'll get really weird behaviour if any library you use uses the `replace` method and it will be difficult to trace the problem.

Comment: I got the point to not do what you've described. It makes totally sense to not touch objects I do not own. I've ended up with `Edit #1` in my question. Is this okay?
At least I dont't want to call the `.toString()` each time to satisfy the compiler

Comment: In my opinion, you should create a function separate from `interface String` that will do what you want. For example `StringUtils.myCustomReplaceFunction("someString", "replaceMe", $(evt.target).data("row-id"));`.

Answer (score 0):

My take on this:

1) The following piece of code does not report any errors on my machine:

```
/// <reference path="typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts" />

"someString".replace("replaceMe", $('#test').data("row-id"));
```

Are you sure that there is an issue in the first place? What is your setting for the TypeScript compiler (i.e. how do you compile TS code)?

2) If you need to implement a `replace` method, you should really consider to create your own module for that otherwise you may cause great confusion for people who read your code:

```
module Project.Utils {
    export class String {   
        public replace = (searchValue: string, replaceValue: any):string =>
        {
            // some replace implementation
        }
    }
}
```

3)The implementation is wrong in the first place because you replace `String.prototype.replace` and then you expect that it will call the native implementation of `String.prototype.replace` and that is not true. Effectively your implementation does NOT do any replacing functionality at all.

```
String.prototype.replace = (searchValue: string, replaceValue: any):string =>
{
    if (replaceValue instanceof String) {
        var stringReplacement = replaceValue.toString();
        return String.prototype.replace(stringReplacement, replaceValue);
    } else {
        return replaceValue;
    }
}
```

4) This codes run perfectly fine in http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground:

```
let n:any = 1; 
"someString".replace("replaceMe", n); 

"someString".replace("replaceMe", <any>5); // explicit cast
```

Comment: 1) It show me the error as described in VS. My settings are to use the TSCompiler 1.6 in %programfiles% or dou you mean some other settings?
2) Good point but is my edit (which makes 3) obsolete) still not calling the correct "internal" replace?
3) I removed my own implementation
4) let me check

Comment: 1) You have shown the error for your _own_ implementation. Not for the actual command: `"someString".replace("replaceMe", $(evt.target).data("row-id"))`

Comment: 3) When you remove your own implementation, it is fine. So `edit #1` is a correct solution.

Comment: Sorry for confusing as of my "implementation" has changed during comments. My issue now can be seen in `Edit #2` (that's why I originally started to think about an overload)
With your example (4.1) it shows no error.

Comment: I would just put there the cast or use the `let variable:any = something`. It is easy to read and a reader quickly understands that.